# Python3-pip wont install package

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install the turtle-package for python3 via pip. But it just returns an error. I recently switched to xubuntu and I am not sure what to do. Any help??

`pip install turtle`

The output I get is:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wewhl4kt/turtle/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wewhl4kt/turtle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ota0vbai
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wewhl4kt/turtle/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-wewhl4kt/turtle/setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: You are trying to install [this package](https://pypi.org/project/turtle/) which was released in 2009. Are you sure you're installing the correct package?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install the [PythonTurtle package](https://pypi.org/project/PythonTurtle/), then from the PyPI website the command to write is

```sh
pip install PythonTurtle
```

or

```sh
python3 -m pip install --user PythonTurtle
PythonTurtle
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the package you're downloading is broken. The maintainer of the project has probably abandoned the project. Are you sure that this is the package you want to be installing?